# Having an issue with Y Finance after upgrading some unrelated stuff

Tags: python, yfinance

I use Y Finance to download data

It was working fine, but is now producing this error message.

Can anyone shine some light on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOK8o.jpg)

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'

I am not sure what the above error means, but all I have done to change things is to update Juypter via Conda and also used the command

"jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10 "

as I was having issues installing fbprophets

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this appears to be an issue with the new version of pandas according to the YFinance github issue [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/939). The way to currently get around this is by installing an older version of pandas like so `pip install pandas==1.3.5`